# Spring boot not returning correct jsp, 404 page error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Hi there i'm fairly new to using the spring framework and im trying to create a webapp to display students from database but i cant seem to get my spring boot app to display the jsp pages i dont know where im going wrong as the i keep getting a 404 for every url i configured in my controller any help on where i'm goin wrong would be appreciated.

Here is my Controller class

```
@Controller
public class StudentConttroller {
    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;
    
    
     @GetMapping("/home")
     public ModelAndView list() {
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("student-list");
         List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
         model.addObject("listStudent", studentList);
         return model;
     }
     
     
     @GetMapping("/student/add")
     public ModelAndView addStudent() { 
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
         Student student = new Student();
         model.addObject("studentForm", student);
         model.setViewName("student-form");
         return model;
     }
     
     
     @GetMapping("/student/edit/{id}")
     public ModelAndView editStudent(@PathVariable int id) {
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(); 
         Student student = studentService.getStudent(id);
         model.addObject("studentForm", student);
         model.setViewName("student-form");
         return model;
     }
     
     
     @GetMapping("/student/add")
     public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("studentForm") Student student) {   
      studentService.addStudent(student);
      return new ModelAndView("redirect:/student/home");
      
     }
     
     @GetMapping("/student/del/{id}")
     public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
         
      studentService.deleteStudent(id);
      return new ModelAndView("redirect:/student/home");
      
     }
}
```

Here is my Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentService implements ServiceInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;
    
    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return (List<Student>) studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudent(int id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(int id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

here is my service interface

```
public interface ServiceInterface {
     public List<Student> getAllStudents();
     public Student getStudent(int id); 
     public void addStudent(Student student);    
     public void deleteStudent(int id);
}
```

and here is my repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {

}
```

here is my main class

```
@ComponentScan({"model", "controller", "repository", "service"})
@EntityScan({"model", "controller", "repository", "service"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Week0708Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Week0708Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

here is the console log i receive when after the app begins

```
2021-08-24 03:52:42.206  INFO 19440 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-08-24 03:52:42.206  INFO 19440 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-08-24 03:52:42.206  INFO 19440 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_, student0_.email as email2_0_, student0_.firstname as firstnam3_0_, student0_.lastname as lastname4_0_ from student student0_
2021-08-24 03:52:43.846  WARN 19440 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/student-list.jsp]
```

here is a pic of my folder structure
[image]

here is my student-list jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*" import="model.Student"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1 shink-to-fit=yes">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384...">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary pd-8">
         <a class="navbar-brand">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XYZ University</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">

            <div class="form container-fluid p-4">
               <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/student" class="btn btn-success" >Add
                    Student</a>
            </div>
            <br>
            
            <!--Assigning ArrayList object containing student data to the local object -->
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <c:forEach var="student" items="${listStudents}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${student.id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${student.name}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${student.email}" /></td>
                    <td>
                      <spring:url value="/student/edit/${student.id}" var="editURL" />
                        <a href="edit?id=<c:out value='${student.id}' />">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <spring:url value="/student/del/${student.id}" var="deleteURL" />     
                        <a href="delete?id=<c:out value='${student.id}'/>" 
                        onclick="return confirm('Do you Really want to delete')">Delete</a>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
                
            </table>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstname + ", lastName=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
```

and console log adds this line after editing this question

```
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_, student0_.email as email2_0_, student0_.firstname as firstnam3_0_, student0_.lastname as lastname4_0_ from student student0_
2021-08-24 12:00:16.337  WARN 2092 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/student-list.html]
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot does not advocate the use of jsp, you need to add the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Added the dependencies but still doesn't return the pages i also tried changing the jsp pages to html the console produces this line now though which previously didnt display ` Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_, student0_.email as email2_0_, student0_.firstname as firstnam3_0_, student0_.lastname as lastname4_0_ from student student0_
2021-08-24 12:00:16.337  WARN 2092 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/student-list.html]`